# Angular Hybrid performance issues in AngularJS Part - Mousemove causes 100% CPU Load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, zonejs, angular-hybrid

#### TLDR

- Move mouse over Angular Components - everything is fine!
- Move mouse over AngularJS Components - Very high CPU Load, performance issues, why?

---

We have an Angular Hybrid Application. The used Versions are:

- Angular: 7.1.3
- AngularJS: 1.7.5
- zone.js: 0.8.28

Unfortunately we have massive performance issues. I found out, that the CPU Load goes to **up to 100%** when you move the mouse.

The strange thing is: The components that are already upgraded to Angular do not have this behaviour! When you move the mouse it doesn't barley has an effect on the CPU Monitor. However in the old AngularJS-Components, which are not upgraded yet, it looks like in the image below.

In zone.js we have used blacklists, like described [here](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/cb12881da7cbc73cf65dd042fad7b0fb)

**polyfills.js**, (gets imported byindex.html)

```
window.__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; /* disable patch requestAnimationFrame */
window.__Zone_disable_on_property = true; /* disable patch onProperty such as onclick */
window.__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = [
    'scroll',
    'mouseenter',
    'mouseleave',
    'mouseout',
    'mouseover',
    'mousewheel',
    'mousemove',
    'dragover',
    'dragenter',
    'dragleave',
]; /* disable patch specified eventNames */

/* black list scroll event handler for onProp */
const targets = [window, Document.prototype, HTMLBodyElement.prototype, HTMLElement.prototype];
window.__Zone_ignore_on_properties = [];
targets.forEach(function(target) {
    window.__Zone_ignore_on_properties.push({
        target: target,
        ignoreProperties: ['scroll', 'mouseenter', 'mouseleave', 'mousemove', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mousewheel'],
    });
});
window.__Zone_disable_XHR = true;
```

[image]

**So how can we fix this issue, that the AngularJS Part does not have this massive performance problem?**

Comment: We finally got rid of AngularJS - no hybrid-mode - no Problem!